# How would I get the amount of weekdays in a month with LocalDate - Java

Tags: java, calendar, weekday, localdate

How would I go about getting the number of weekdays (Monday though Friday) in a month with `LocalDate`? I've never used `java.time` before so I don't know all of its workings. I've been looking on this site to no avail along with searching for an answer. I also do not want to use any external libraries.

Example: As of this month, April of 2018, there are 21 weekdays. And next month there is 23 weekdays.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected input/output?

Comment: @idos Does the example help?

Comment: I don't know of an elegant solution, but the bruteforce is obvious: Create a [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for the first day of the respective month. Loop until the end of the month using ld.plusDays(1) and use ld.getDayOfWeek() to see which [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) you're dealing with. Then conditionally add to your businessday counter.

Comment: *"I don't know all of its workings"* Then you should **read the documentation** so you can **learn**, e.g. the javadoc of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: @Andreas I am reading it, but I'm also coming here for understanding and to ask if somethings possible. That's the whole point of this site.

Comment: By 'business days', do you mean how many Monday-Fridays or do you want to exclude public holidays? The later cannot be done with internal libraries alone since it is dependent on country and varies with time.

Comment: @DHa By my knowledge, here in the US, a business day is usually Monday-Friday. And now since I'm thinking about it, saying weekday would have probably been a better title.

Comment: @TechNGamer Then you should edit the question and correct the title, to clarify it

Comment: In case you’re interested, I compared the results from the two methods by @Andreas and the method from your own answer on all months from 1905 through 2070. They agreed. So seem to be correct all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If desired, see optimized brute-force solution at the end*

Here is a non-brute-force implementation to *calculate* week days (Mon-Fri) in a month.

It uses [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) instead of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), since the day-of-month value is meaningless to the calculation.

```
public static int weekDaysInMonth(YearMonth yearMonth) {
    int len = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth(); // 28-31, supporting leap year
    int dow = yearMonth.atDay(1).getDayOfWeek().getValue(); // 1=Mon, 7=Sun
    return (dow <= 5 ? Math.min(len - 8, 26 - dow) : Math.max(len + dow - 16, 20));
}
```

Here is an overload taking a `LocalDate`, so it's easy to call if that's what you have.

```
public static int weekDaysInMonth(LocalDate date) {
    return weekDaysInMonth(YearMonth.from(date));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(weekDaysInMonth(LocalDate.parse("2018-04-15"))); // April 15, 2018
System.out.println(weekDaysInMonth(YearMonth.of(2018, 5)));         // May 2018
```

*Output*

```
21
23
```

---

**Explanation of Formula**

The formula in the `return` statement was created by examining the expected return value for every combination of `len` (number of days in month, 28 - 31) and `dow` (day-of-week of first day of month, 1=Mon - 7=Sun):

```
   |  1   2   3   4   5    6   7
   | Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr   Sa  Su
---+----------------------------
28 | 20  20  20  20  20   20  20
29 | 21  21  21  21  21   20  20
30 | 22  22  22  22  21   20  21
31 | 23  23  23  22  21   21  22
```

**Explanation for `dow <= 5` (Mon-Fri)**

Initially there are `len - 8` weekdays, i.e. we subtract the 4 weekends that always exist in a month.

As we get to Thursday and Friday, we need to cap that for the 1 or 2 weekend days we lose. If you look at the 31-day row, we cap it at `26 - dow`, i.e. for Friday (`dow=5`) we cap at `21`, and for Thursday (`dow=4`) we cap at `22`. For Monday-Wednesday, we also cap, but cap is equal to or higher than initial calculation, so it doesn't matter.

Capping is done using `min(xxx, cap)` method, so we get:

```
min(len - 8, 26 - dow)
```

**Explanation for `dow >= 6` (Sat-Sun)**

You can see a small triangle in the lower-right corner. If we extend that pattern, we get:

```
   |  4   5   6   7
---+---------------
28 | 16  17  18  19
29 | 17  18  19  20
30 | 18  19  20  21
31 | 19  20  21  22
```

As a formula, that is `len + dow - 16`.

Comparing that to original grid, numbers bottom out at `20`, which is done using `max(xxx, bottom)` method, so we get:

```
max(len + dow - 16, 20)
```

**Conclusion**

Finally we combine the two using ternary conditional operator:

```
dow <= 5  ?  min(len - 8, 26 - dow)  :  max(len + dow - 16, 20)
```

Full Java statement is then:

```
return (dow <= 5 ? Math.min(len - 8, 26 - dow) : Math.max(len + dow - 16, 20));
```

---

**Brute-Force Solution**

If you prefer a brute-force solution, you can ease it by skipping the first 4 weeks that always exists in a month:

```
public static int weekDaysInMonth(LocalDate refDate) {
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = refDate.withDayOfMonth(1);
    LocalDate nextMonth = firstOfMonth.plusMonths(1);
    int days = 20;
    for (LocalDate date = firstOfMonth.plusDays(28); date.isBefore(nextMonth); date = date.plusDays(1))
        if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() <= 5) // 1=Mon - 5=Fri, i.e. not 6=Sat and 7=Sun
            days++;
    return days;
}
```

Comment: Few years later noone will be able to decypher the `return` formula.

Comment: @lexicore That's why I added the basis for the formula to the end of the answer, to at least have some reference to how I came up with that one.

Comment: Yes, I have no doubts it is correct. :) However I personally would opt to the brute-force method just because it's easier to understand.

Comment: It does look nicer and has fewer lines of code than the brute force one I thought of. However, I am not able to understand the return statement. Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @lexicore Few years later (unless someone bothers to change the Gregorian calender) it will still work efficiently so no one will care to look at it :) Personally I would comment the code with a link to this question :)

Answer (score 3):

So, thanks to Dreamspace President for helping me find a solution (even though it is a brute force way) when he said this:

> Create a LocalDate for the first day of the respective month. Loop until the end of the month using ld.plusDays(1) and use ld.getDayOfWeek() to see which DayOfWeek you're dealing with.

This is what I've found to work:

```
public static int businessDaysInMonth(final LocalDate ld) {

    int weekDays = 0;
    LocalDate date = ld.withDayOfMonth(1);
    final int intendedMonthValue = ld.getMonthValue();
    do {
        final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();

        if (dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY && dayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            weekDays++;
        }

        date = date.plusDays(1);
    } while (date.getMonthValue() == intendedMonthValue);

    return weekDays;
}
```

Comment: You forget about hollidays and other not working days!

Comment: Andreas' solution is quite sexy (though I didn't check if the results are correct in all cases, but I assume so), e.g. it deals with leap years without even having to mention them. In your brute force implementation, you obviously should use more variables to reduce method calls, also you can compare Enum values directly (with ==), you don't have to use .ordinal() or (like you did) .getValue() //////// Actually, regarding leap years: It should be entirely sufficient that you keep adding 1 day until the ld.getMonthValue() changes.

Comment: Correction: It IS entirely sufficient to check if the month changes. https://i.imgur.com/bjN0im1.png

Comment: `LocalDate.of(ld.getYear(), intendedMonthValue, 1)` is better written as `ld.withDayOfMonth(1)`

Comment: It’s certainly more readable than the code in Andreas’ answer (I have upvoted both, though).

Comment: The loop would be more obvious as a `for` loop, i.e. `for (LocalDate date = ld.withDayOfMonth(1); date.getMonthValue() == intendedMonthValue; date = date.plusDays(1))`

Comment: @DreamspacePresident I think that replacing `daysInMonth` with the very generic `ret` is bad purification.

Comment: @Andreas I think a `for` loop would make it a bit harder to read since it's not a collection. A `for` loop just seems better suited for collections while a `while` and `do-while` loops seem better suited for these types of calculations. Also, I changed ret to weekDays, however, me being tired didn't properly changed it.

Comment: @TechNGamer You're thinking of the enhanced-for loop, `for (E value : collection)`. I'm referring to a normal counting loop, such as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, i.e. set first value, loop while condition is good, increment to next value, keeping all the looping logic together. It shows that this is a simple incrementing loop, for a particular range of values, i.e. all the days of the given month.

Comment: @Andreas You're right about withDayOfMonth(1) and the for loop (more compact/expressive). I disagree about "ret": It expresses intention. Everything in a method (that returns a value) gravitates around it, so I assume a variable with a more speaking name to be serving the needs of the return value, not to be the return value itself.  The method name kinda is the true name of ret. But I agree that if you're surfing your code, having a ret with a speaking name may be more helpful, because you don't have to make yourself aware first of where exactly you are.

Comment: @Andreas A for-each (or as Java calls it an enhanced-for loop) in my mind is a for loop where position doesn't matter while a regular for loop, position matters. Either way, a for loop just seems like it's more for collections of objects rather than anything else. A while and do-while seem better for things that aren't collections, but I do see your point. A for loop counts and has everything on one line for its statement.

Comment: @TechNGamer An enhanced for loop would be for **C**ollections, a standard for loop for **c**ollections, and your sequence of days of the one month certainly is a **c**ollection. But I think we're in matter-of-taste territory (same for the "ret" name question).